# bottomBar of scaffold is not visible at all

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to display a bottomBar in a scaffold but I can't see it at all. I do have LazyVerticalGrid in case it matters. What could be the problem?

Scaffold(

```
topBar = {Text(text="top bar")},

content = {  paddingValues ->
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(paddingValues)

    ) {
        
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(1),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
        ) {
            items(fruits) { f: Fruit ->
                FruitCard(f)
            }
        }
    }
          }
,
bottomBar = {   Text(text="Bottom Bar") }
```

)

I have removed the vertical grid and I still don't see the bottom bar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this **modifier**：`Modifier.navigationBarsPadding()`

**Example:**

```
Scaffold(
        topBar = { Text(text = "top bar") },
        content = { paddingValues ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(paddingValues)
            ) {
                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    columns = GridCells.Fixed(1),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
                ) {
                    items(fruits) { f: Fruit ->
                        FruitCard(f)
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        bottomBar = {
            Column(Modifier.navigationBarsPadding()) {
                Text(text = "Bottom Bar")
            }
        }
    )
```